# Как объединить два регулярных выражения?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка в ней есть имя и фамилия и телефон нужно отсеять всё кроме имени и телефона.

```
$subject="Емец Вероника,Вероника,27.08.2012,п,4,7,1996,380989893759,veroni-333@mail.ru,0,0,0,0,,0,0,0,0,,0,0,0,0"
```

Есть 2 регулярных выражения.

Первое:

```
 @[\d(\s{*})]{7,14}@iu //найдёт телефон "380989893759"
```

Второе:

```
 @[а-яё(\s{1})]{7,30}@iu //находит словосочетание типа "Емец Вероника"
```

Как эти два регулярных выражения объединить?

Comment: Если порядок данных разделенных запятой строгий, то можно и без регулярок обойтись: `explode` / `preg_split`, etc. и брать нужные элементы массива.

Comment: @Deonis preg_split - это тоже с помощью регулярок )

Comment: [Это какое-то отношение имеет к этому вопросу?](https://vk.com/topic-126980889_34516102?offset=60)

Comment: Даже заходить в вк не хочу это наркотик.

Comment: @DROP, да )) Ну, я с тем смыслом, что разбить просто по запятой. Меньше телодвижений в регулярке - меньше неприятных неожиданностей.

Comment: https://ideone.com/rbGVcr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте именованные подмаски `(?<name>...)` *(на месте троеточия пишется шаблон)* и символьные классы: литеральный `\pL` с указанием минимального количества букв в имени *(три и более `{3,}`)*, и числовой `\d{12}`. Объединить эти два шаблона можно с помощью альтернативы ИЛИ `|`, и всё в сборе записать так:

```
$str = 'Емец Вероника,Вероника,27.08.2012,п,4,7,1996,380989893759,veroni-333@mail.ru,0,0,0,0,,0,0,0,0,,0,0,0,0';

$patt = '~(?<=,)(?<name>\pL{3,})(?=,)|(?<phone>\d{12})~u';
preg_match_all($patt, $str, $arr);
$arr = array_map('array_filter', $arr);

var_dump($arr['name'], $arr['phone']);
```

Результат:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => string 'Вероника' (length=16)

array (size=1)
  1 => string '380989893759' (length=12)
```

---

> *А можно указать что бы не "или" условие было а "и" я как бы хотел почистить строку и получить строку*

Для поиска и замены можно использовать preg_replace():

```
$str = 'Емец Вероника,Вероника-Никитишна,27.08.2012,п,4,7,1996,380989893759,veroni-333@mail.ru,0,0,0,0,,0,0,0,0,,0,0,0,0';

$patt = '~.+?(?<=,)(\pL{3,}(?:-\pL+)?)(?=,)|.+(\d{12}).+~u';

echo preg_replace($patt, '$1 $2', $str);
```

Результат:

```
Вероника-Никитишна 380989893759
```

Comment: требуется пояснение про ?<name> про это ?<phone> и вот это а именно p откуда ты вообще узнал? pL{3,}

Comment: А можно указать что бы не "или" условие было а "и" я как бы хотел почистить строку и получить строку.

Comment: Смотрите а можно ли как то поставить диапазон чтобы была не граница слова из трех букв а слово сочетание. Ну и подскажи маны откуда вы смотрели, а то я перечитал уже кучу всего.

Comment: да подойдет как вариант но и хотелось бы маны которыми вы пользуетесь. я пользуюсь вот этим http://www.exlab.net/tools/sheets/regexp.html

Comment: спасибо буду читать.

Comment: а у меня вот такой вот паттер подходит. как его сложить в одн строку. $pattern='#(\d{7,12})|([а-яё(\s{1})]{7,30})#iu';